# beamercolorbox width whole page but text in normal textwidth

Tags: beamer, margins

I would like a beamercolorbox to extend wd=paperwidth, but text content only to cover the original textwidth and position. Is there some recommendation for doing it?

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 3):

Not a `beamercolorbox` but a `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[extrude left by=1cm, extrude right by=1cm]
text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would work perfectly fine, but I need it in a site template so beamercolorbox is the, well, only way to go I think.